# Formatting Textbox into MM/YYYY

Tags: c#, string, webforms, textbox

I have a textbox in my web forms (ASP.NET Web Forms) which I want to show something like this:

> MM/YYYY

I want this "/" in the middle when user is entering the month and year. How should I do this on C#?

Comment: What kind of application: ASP.NET, WinForms, Console, WPF, Silverlight, XBox 360, Windows Phone 7, Zune, ... Obviously depending on the target platform the answers will vary as you understand that textboxes are all around us and we cannot be guessing about which one you are talking about in your question. The fact that you have tagged your question with `textbox` simply doesn't bring any useful information about your scenario.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, mine on XBox 360.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [MaskedTextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class (for Windows Forms anyway... I see you've now specified it as Web Forms).

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look at the Masked Input jQuery plugin:

https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Seems like it would fit nicely for what you need to do.

Implementation looks like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

You can see demos here:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If you're using Windows Forms, take a look at the [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) class. If you're using WPF, take a look at the [`FilteredTextBox`](http://www.codeplex.com/WPFDeveloperTools) or perhaps the [`MaskedTextBox`](http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Home&ProjectName=avaloncontrolslib) control.</strike> If WebForms ASP.NET, there are some other options like this [Masked Textbox](http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/item.aspx?i=387) or various jquery possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

We will either use a date control that supports month / year selections OR split the field into two separate fields, one for month the other for year.

For a web app, it's usually better to just split it out.  That way you cover the most possibilities.

If you insist on keeping it in one field and don't want to use a purpose built control, then don't worry about the slash and do some parsing once the field is posted... But this should be a last resort.